# leetcode two sum problem algorithm efficiency

Tags: python, algorithm

**Problem:** Given an array of integers nums and an integer target, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

You can return the answer in any order.

> Input: nums = [2,7,11,15],
> target = 9
> Output: [0,1]
> Explanation: Because nums[0] + nums[1] == 9, we return [0, 1].

Here's my code:

```
def twoSum(nums, target):
    cnt = 0
    i = 0
    while cnt < len(nums):
        temp = 0
        if i == cnt:
            i += 1
        else:
            temp = nums[cnt] + nums[i]
            if temp == target and i < cnt:
                return [i,cnt]
            i += 1
        if i == len(nums)-1:
            i = 0
            cnt += 1
```

The code seems to work fine for 55/57 test cases. But it doesn't work for really big input cases. But i don't understand why this is happening because i have used only one loop and the time complexity should be O(N) which is efficient enough to run in the given time. So any idea what am i missing? And what can i do to make the algorithm more efficient?

Comment: Your code is not O(n)  but O(n^2). You more or less hid the loop on `i`, but it gets incremented from 0 to `len(nums)` for each value of `cnt`.

Comment: Note that starting again at 0, you test again values that you already tried. Also, you access `nums[cnt]` again and again. Use `for value in your_list` rather than looping on the indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a dictionary of the last position of the complement value of each number. Then use it to find the position of the value for which the complement exists in the list (at a greater index in case you have a value that is half the target):

```
nums   = [2,7,11,15]
target = 9

pos = {target-n:i for i,n in enumerate(nums)}
sol = next([i,pos[n]] for i,n in enumerate(nums) if i<pos.get(n,i))

print(sol)
[0, 1]
```

*This works in O(n) time and space*

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't really `O(n)`, it's actually `O(n^2)` in disguise.

You go through `i` `O(n)` times for each `cnt` (and then reset `i` back to 0), and go through `cnt` `O(n)` times.

For a more efficient algorithm, sites like this one (https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-implement-the-two-sum-problem-in-python) have it down pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

if we`re not talking about space complexity:

```py
def search(values, target):
    hashmap = {}
    
    for i in range(len(values)):
        current = values[i]
        if target - current in hashmap:
            return current, hahsmap[target - current]
        
        hashmap[current] = i

    return None
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the time complexity but I think this solution will be better. `p1` and `p2` act as two pointers of indexes:

```
def twoSum(nums, target):
    nums2 = nums[:]
    nums2.sort()
    p1 = 0
    p2 = len(nums2)-1
    while nums2[p1]+nums2[p2]!=target:
        if nums2[p1]+nums2[p2]<target:
            p1 += 1
        elif nums2[p1]+nums2[p2]>target:
            p2 -= 1
    return nums.index(nums2[p1]), nums.index(nums2[p2])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for i, num in enumerate(nums):
    complement = target - num
    if complement in D:
        return [D[complement], i]  
    D[num] = i
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**